# SSH Server Not Responding To Connection Request

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, openssh

I'm attempting to set up an SSH server on my local machine using OpenSSH. When I try to SSH from a remote host into my local SSH server, the SSH server doesn't respond and the request times out. I'm pretty sure there's a really obvious fix for this that I'm simply overlooking.

Here's what happens when I try to SSH in from a remote host:

```
yoshimi@robots:/$ ssh -vv volt@99.3.26.94
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 99.3.26.94 [99.3.26.94] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address 99.3.26.94 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 99.3.26.94 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Where `robots` is my remote host, and `99.3.26.94` is my local SSH server.

**SSH Is Running**

```
volt@arnold:~$ ps -A | grep sshd
 5784 ?        00:00:00 sshd
```

Where `arnold` is my local SSH server.

**Port Forwarding Is Set Up On the Router**

I've got my home router set up to forward ports 80 and 22 to my SSH server. Interestingly, port 80 worked without a hitch -- goes straight to the Apache web directory. Port 22 -- not so much.

**NMap Says It's Filtered**

```
yoshimi@robots:/$ nmap -p 22 99.3.26.94

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-06-02 14:45 EDT
Nmap scan report for 99-3-26-94.lightspeed.bcvloh.sbcglobal.net (99.3.26.94)
Host is up (0.33s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.59 seconds
```

Where `robots` is my remote host, and `99.3.26.94` is my local SSH server.

**It's Not IPTables (I think)**

```
volt@arnold:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

...And I don't have any other firewalls in place -- it's a relatively fresh Debian netinst.

So, then: *What else could it be?* It certainly appears to be a firewall-y sort of thing to just ignore traffic, but if it's not the router, it's not iptables, and it's not another firewall on the SSH server, ...what the heck else is there??

**EDIT: NetStat Server Output**

From the SSH Server:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      5784/sshd
```

Comment: do you see port 22 open when you run `sudo netstat -ntlup` on the ssh server? If NMAP says its filtered, than the port is inaccessible. your ISP may even be blocking ssh connection attempts upstream. try a different port (something above 1024), and test that it is visible with http://canyouseeme.org/ after you have set up the port forwarding.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankThomas -- port does appear to be open via `netstat` (see edit), but instructing the router to forward traffic to port 22999 to the SSH server's port 22 gives the same disappointing result -- NMap says it's filtered.

Comment: is robots on a different LAN than Arnold?

Comment: As a test, see the netstat output for apache is it also 0 ::: xx?  And as another test, Try nmap to port 83 (a port where you have no server and no port forwarding, do you get closed or filtered.. )  And as yet another test, try putting the ssh server on port 80 see if nmap sees it, see if ssh client sees it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Very Disappointing Self-Answer**

Having set this problem aside for a day and come back to it, I was both relieved and perturbed (more perturbed than relieved) to find that everything was, mysteriously, working properly.

**So, What Was the Issue?**

No settings were changed or adjusted -- not on the router, not on the SSH server, and not on the SSH client's machine. It's fairly safe to say it was the router not handling the incoming traffic properly, in spite of proper settings. Given that dinky home router software isn't *really* designed to deal with port forwarding, it took the poor guy a while to implement the necessary changes.

**But It's Been Like 6 Hours!!**

Yeah dude, I know. I spent all day trying to figure out what was wrong -- and didn't ever find it because there *wasn't* anything wrong. Evidently, it can take 6 hours -- possibly more -- for the router settings to take effect.

**So How Do I Know If This Is My Issue?**

A nifty tool I came across during this escapade is `tcpdump`. This lean little guy sniffs traffic for you, offering valuable insight into what's actually going on. Plus, he's got some super filtering features that allow you to narrow down exactly what you want to look at/for. For example, the command:

```
tcpdump -i wlan1 port 22 -n -Q inout
```

Tells `tcpdump` to look for traffic via the wlan1 interface (`-i` = 'interface'), only through port 22, ignore DNS name resolution (`-n` = 'no name resolution'), and we want to see both incoming and outgoing traffic (`-Q` accepts `in`, `out`, or `inout`; `inout` is the default).

By running this command on your SSH server while attempting to connect via a remote machine, it quickly becomes clear where precisely the problem lies. There are, essentially, 3 possibilities:

1. If you're seeing *incoming* traffic from the remote machine, but *no outgoing* traffic from your local server, the problem lies with the server: there's probably a firewall rule that needs to be changed, etc.
2. If you're seeing *both incoming and outgoing*, but your remote machine isn't receiving the response, it's most likely the router: it's allowing the incoming traffic, but dropping your outgoing packets.
3. If there's *no traffic at all*, that's probably a router issue as well: the remote machine's `SYN` packets are being ignored and dropped by the router before they even reach your server.

And once you've discovered where the problem lies, a fix is (usually) trivial.